# Is it safe to run terraform init multiple times

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

I have an entire infrastructure built with `terraform aws`

While trying to use `data "archive_file"` for `lambda`...

the terminal returned this message:

```
 Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
│ 
│ Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
│ resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,
│ don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.
│ 
│ Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
│ configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
│ requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".
│ 
│ failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive" to obtain schema: unknown provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/archive"
│
```

I am worried about running `terraform init` and have some side effects that will probably wipe out the entire infrastructure...

Is it safe to run this command at this point?

Comment: Yes, init is safe to run.

Comment: Yes, you have to run `terraform init` any time you make changes to providers. If you're worried about it, just backup your state file (you should be doing that already anyway).

Comment: @MarkB correct, the state is already backend on `dynamodb`. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `terraform init` command prepares the working directory by downloading provider plugins & modules and configures the backend store. It doesn't touch your infrastructure. See [the manual page](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/init) for more details.
Infrastructure changes are done by the `terraform apply` and `terraform destroy` commands.